# I am trying update multiple values from another table by multiple the two colums of two table on th basis of date and symbol

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
UPDATE wpcurrate
SET usd = (SELECT (mo.price * wpcurrate.midprice) as USD
           FROM mo, wpcurrate
           WHERE wpcurrate.symbol = mo.symbol)
WHERE mo.curdatetime BETWEEN '2015-07-01 12:00:00 AM' AND '2015-07-31 11:59:59 PM'
```

It shows following error:

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "mo.curdatetime" could not be bound.
>
> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The multi-part identifier "mo.curdatetime" could not be bound.

Comment: Please update your question with the flavor of SQL you are using.  I'm guessing MySQL but then again I can't be certain.

Comment: Sql server 2008 im using

Comment: Simply i have to update the rows of a column on the basis of mutiplication of two columns of 2 tables. Both have Symbol and date common.But the date range should be july month only i have to update on ly those values.

Comment: I think the recent edits changed the original query.

Comment: Do you have `curdatetime` column in your `mo` table?

Comment: yes curdatetime in mo table

Comment: `mo` is not defined outside your **inner** `SELECT`.

Comment: THanks alot  i got the answser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
UPDATE wp
SET wp.usd = m.price * wp.midprice
FROM wpcurrate AS wp
    INNER JOIN mo AS m ON wp.symbol = m.symbol
WHERE m.curdatetime BETWEEN '2015-07-01 12:00:00 AM' AND '2015-07-31 11:59:59 PM'
```

Comment: @AsifGanaie Pls vote this answer is correct for you :)

Comment: @AsifGanaie you need 15 reputation to upvote i upvoted your question now you have 13 ..two more needed

Comment: need 15 reputation to upvote i have 13 now i need 2 more can u then i can vote u @trungtin1710

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE w
SET w.usd = mo.price * w.wpcurrate.midprice
                 FROM wpcurrate w
Inner Join mo on w.symbol = mo.symbol
WHERE mo.curdatetime  between  '2015-07-01 12:00:00 AM' and '2015-07-31 11:59:59 PM'
```

You need to do a join operation to achieve this

Comment: Sachu-----Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: THanks alot  i got the answser

Comment: @Asifganaie whats the answer?

Comment: I need  15 reputation to upvote  i have 13 now i need 2 more can u then i can vote u